# Removing programs for specific computers

Tags: group-policy, deployment

i am currently working for a company as an intern.

i have been given the task to remove Java on specific computers that have already installed the program manually.

this means that there's no GPO with a published MSI of this application.

is it, in any way possible, that i will be able to remove this program from their computer with a GPO?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this just a one-time only removal? First thing that comes to mind is a start-up/shutdown script setting. Then remove the GPO after etc.

Personally I wouldn’t elect to use a GPO to remove some software, psexec comes to mind or even scheduled task scripts.

Up to you.